# admin as username and password not working in WSO2 console

Tags: console, wso2, admin

Just started a wso2server in an Ubuntu machine and open the console for the first login and, unfortunately, admin as username and password is giving me an Error 403 - Forbidden. Any clue on this?

Regards,

Norberto Neto

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JDK 1.8, some versions like JDK1.8.0_151 are affected by a known issue related to GZIP decoding [1]. As a workaround you could use JDK1.8.0_144 or JDK1.8.0_077 updates.

Else you can disable GZIP decoding for current JDK with following steps.

1. Open the catalina-server.xml file from the
   /repository/conf/tomcat/ directory.
2. Set the compression parameter false for each connector configurations.
3. Restart the server.

Please refer documentation for more informations [2]

[1] https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189789

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Installation+Prerequisites

Comment: Thanks for you answer Tharik. I was really using the JDK 1.8.0_162 and only realize it must be the 162ea to work. I'm using 144 and it's working now. Regards.